# My ANTLR grammar with optional token fails on simple statements

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, antlr2

I use ANTLR 2.7 to create a grammar to parse simple expressions like

```
1
2%
(3%)
(4)
((5))
((6%))
```

It's simple numbers which can have paranthesis and optional percent characters

My grammar looks like this:

```
class MyParser extends Parser;
options {
  k=2;
  buildAST = true;
}

parexpr
  : variable
  | LPAREN^ parexpr RPAREN!
  ;

variable
  : (NUMBER PCT) => NUMBER PCT^
  | NUMBER
  ;

class MyLexer extends Lexer;
options {
  k=6;
}
LPAREN:  '(';
RPAREN:  ')';
DOT: '.';
PCT: '%';
protected
DIGIT:  '0'..'9';
NUMBER: (DIGIT)+ (DOT (DIGIT)+)*;
```

I can successfully parse e.g.

```
(1)
(2%)
```

But it fails to parse a single number:

```
1
```

If I remove either `| LPAREN^ parexpr RPAREN!` or `: (NUMBER PCT) => NUMBER PCT^` then I can parse a single number (but obviously not the other expressions).

I do not understand why I cannot parse a single number with this grammar..?

Note that I am working on a project that was implemented with this version a long time ago, and I'm just extending the existing things.

Comment: Because I am working on a project that was implemented with this version a long time ago, and I'm just extending the existing things. Afaik ANTLR is not backwards compatible :-(

Comment: That's a sound reason. I just wanted to double check you're not accidentally starting something new with this older version.